# NHibernate Validator: Using Attributes vs. Using ValidationDefs

Tags: nhibernate, validation

I've been using NH Validator for some time, mostly through `ValidationDef`s, but I'm still not sure about two things:

1. Is there any special benefit of using `ValidationDef` for simple/standard validations (like `NotNull`, `MaxLength` etc)?
2. I'm worried about the fact that those two methods throw different kinds of exceptions on validation, for example:

   - `ValidationDef`'s `Define.NotNullable()` throws `PropertyValueException`
   - When using `[NotNull]` attribute, an  `InvalidStateException` is thrown.

This makes me think mixing these two approaches isn't a good idea - it will be very difficult to handle validation exceptions consistently. Any suggestions/recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ValidationDef** is probably more suitable for [business-rules validation](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/01/nhibernatevalidator-changing-validation.html) even if, having said that, I used it even for simple validation. There's more [here](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/10/nhibernatevalidator-extending_26.html).
What I like about **ValidationDef** is the fact that it has got a fluent interface. 
I've been playing around with this engine for quite a while and I've put together something that works quite well for me.
I've defined an interface:

```
public interface IValidationEngine
{
    bool IsValid(Entity entity);
    IList<Validation.IBrokenRule> Validate(Entity entity);
}
```

Which is implemented in my validation engine:

```
public class ValidationEngine : Validation.IValidationEngine
{
    private NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine _Validator;

    public ValidationEngine()
    {
        var vtor = new NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine();
        var configuration = new FluentConfiguration();
        configuration
            .SetDefaultValidatorMode(ValidatorMode.UseExternal)
            .Register<Data.NH.Validation.User, Domain.User>()
            .Register<Data.NH.Validation.Company, Domain.Company>()
            .Register<Data.NH.Validation.PlanType, Domain.PlanType>();
        vtor.Configure(configuration);
        this._Validator = vtor;
    }

    public bool IsValid(DomainModel.Entity entity)
    {
        return (this._Validator.IsValid(entity));
    }

    public IList<Validation.IBrokenRule> Validate(DomainModel.Entity entity)
    {
        var Values = new List<Validation.IBrokenRule>();
        NHibernate.Validator.Engine.InvalidValue[] values = this._Validator.Validate(entity);
        if (values.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                Values.Add(
                    new Validation.BrokenRule()
                    {
                        // Entity = value.Entity as BpReminders.Data.DomainModel.Entity,
                        // EntityType = value.EntityType,
                        EntityTypeName = value.EntityType.Name,
                        Message = value.Message,
                        PropertyName = value.PropertyName,
                        PropertyPath = value.PropertyPath,
                        // RootEntity = value.RootEntity as DomainModel.Entity,
                        Value = value.Value
                    });
            }
        }
        return (Values);
    }
}
```

I plug all my domain rules in there.
I bootstrap the engine at the app startup:

```
For<Validation.IValidationEngine>()
    .Singleton()
    .Use<Validation.ValidationEngine>();
```

Now, when I need to validate my entities before save, I just use the engine:

```
if (!this._ValidationEngine.IsValid(User))
{
    BrokenRules = this._ValidationEngine.Validate(User);
}
```

and return, eventually, the collection of broken rules.